Finding All Left Inverses For a $3\times2$ Matrix
I’m trying to find all left inverses for this matrix A: \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 \\2 & -4 \\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}
I know to start by row reducing [A⊤|I], which gives me: \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{10} & -\frac{1}{10}
\end{bmatrix}
However, I’m confused on how to interpret this. Does column 3 not being zeroes mean there’s a free variable?
And just by plugging in numbers,\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{5} & \frac{3}{10} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{5} & -\frac{1}{10} & 0\end{bmatrix} seems to be one of the left inverses for A, but I’m not sure why it looks transposed (since a solution I found on the internet that had a third column of zeroes did not seem to have to transpose the right part of the matrix to obtain a general solution), and I’m not sure how to obtain a general form of the answer since if the last column isn’t zero, it no longer is a left inverse of A.
Apologies for any bad English and thank you for any help in advance!

Another approach is to solve a linear system of 4 equations in 6 variables. See WA

Let me answer the specific questions you asked:

yes, column 3 tells you something. It shows that the vector $v$, which I'll use near the end of my answer, exists.

the solution on the internet SHOULD have transposed and gotten what you got. You might want to multiply their solution by $A$ on the right and see whether you get $I_2$ or not. The need for the xpose comes because you transposed $A$ when setting up your row-reduction. You could also have left $A$ un-transposed, added the identity at the bottom (getting a 5 x 2 augmented matrix), and then column-reduced...but frankly, everyone gets used to row reduction, and it's easiest to do what you're familiar with to avoid arithmetic errors, etc.


Now here are my thoughts as I look at/work through the problem. (I've done lots of math, but I've never wanted to find a general form for all left-inverses of a particular matrix, so this is partly just my "apply standard ideas and see where they lead me" trail of thoughts.)
What you've written shows that if you take $2/5$ of the first row of $A$ plus $3/10$ of the second row, you get $\pmatrix{1\\0}$,  and similarly for the other pair of numbers.
But you could also find such a combination for the first and third rows of $A$, or even the second and third rows of $A$. So there are many possible left-inverses. If you called those first three $B_1, B_2, B_3$, then you have
$$
B_1 A  = I_2 \\
B_2 A = I_2 \\
B_3A = I_2
$$
so if you took a combination like
$$
Q = c_1 B_1 + c_2 B_2 + c_3 B_3
$$
where the $c_i$ are real numbers, you'd have
\begin{align}
QA 
&= c_1 B_1 A + c_2 B_2 A + c_3 B_3 A\\
&= c_1 I_2 + c_2 I_2 + c_3 I_2\\ 
&= (c_1 + c_2  + c_3) I_2
\end{align}
which would again be $I_2$ as long as $c_1 + c_2 + c_3 = 1$.
So how can we be sure we've found all possible solutions? And are some of them redundant (i.e., have we listed them more than once?) ?
Suppose that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are both left-inverses for $A$. Then
\begin{align}
(C_1 - C_2) A = I_2 - I_2 
\end{align}
so in fact $(C_1 - C_2) A = 0$. That means that left-multiplying $A$ by either row of $C_1 - C_2$ gives you the zero vector. Which also means that each row of that difference $C_1 - C_2$ must be in the left nullspace of $A$.
A little fiddling (perhaps with your row-reduced matrix) shows you that this left nullspace is 1-dimensional, and is spanned by
$$
v = \pmatrix{-2 &-\frac12 &1}
$$
Let's start with the left inverse you've shown, which I'll call $C_1$. It has rows
$$
w_1 =\pmatrix{ \frac25 &\frac3{10} &0} \text{ and }\\
w_2 =\pmatrix{ \frac15 &-\frac1{10} &0} \\
$$
so I can informally write
$$
C_1 = \pmatrix{w_1\\w_2}.
$$
Then I can derive from this ANOTHER left inverse by adding a multiple of $v$ to either row, getting (in the most general case)
$$
C_2 = \pmatrix{w_1 + av\\w_2 + bv}
$$
for any real numbers $a$ and $b$. And this gives me a general formula for all possible left-inverses of $A$.
I apologize for this somewhat rambling answer. It's basically a transcript of what went through my head as I tried to think about the problem.
This also shows that in my earlier comments, having all three of $B_1, B_2, B_3$ was unnecessary. In fact, if you work things out, you'll see that $B_3$, for instance, can be written as a combination of $B_1$ and $B_2$, so we only need two of them. Thus the space of left-inverses is really only two dimensional. (Indeed, it's a 2D affine subspace of the space of $2 \times 3$ matrices.)
